# Not able to convert GMT timezone to PDT using CONVERT_TZ function in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timezone

I am not able to convert GMT timezone to PDT using CONVERT_TZ function in mysql while I am able to convert GMT/UTC timezone to MET/GMT timezone.

```
MySQL Query :

SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','UTC','Asia/Jakarta') AS time;

+---------------------+
| time                |
+---------------------+
| 2004-01-01 19:00:00 |
+---------------------+

SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2015-10-21 12:50:00','GMT','PDT') AS time;

+------+
| time |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will probably help you understand why https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html It sounds like you do not have that timezone defined in MySQL's timezone tables

Comment: I have also loaded all timezone in mysql tables using mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql but still i'm not getting exact value @RiggsFolly

Comment: Well try this query `SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone_name` Do you see a name column with PDT in it? I doubt it!

Comment: When I search for PDT after query, I found this two values. right/PST8PDT
posix/SystemV/PST8PDT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that there is a `PST8PDT` timezone name, is that what you are looking for?

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2015-10-21 12:50:00','GMT','PST8PDT') AS time;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I want. but still I am not getting CDT time using SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2015-10-21 15:08:00','GMT','CST6CDT') AS time; actually, I am getting wrong time using this query.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use three-letter time zone abbreviations.  While a few are supported, in general there are many ambiguities.  For example, CST has five different interpretations.  You can review [the list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) for more examples of conflicts.

Additionally, time zone abbreviations generally refer to only a *portion* of the time zone.  For example, Pacific time uses PST in the winter, and PDT in the summer.   Some of the entries in the time zone database attempt to account for this (using PDT rules for daylight time when PST is specified), but others are strictly fixed offsets and do not switch.  Making sense of which ones are which is futile.

You should also not use time zones like `PST8PDT`, as these are primarily there for backwards compatibility with older POSIX standards.  The problem with this style of time zones is that they don't account for any history of changes.  Time zones change their rules over time, such as when the US changed its DST rules in 2007, or when Russia changed its standard offsets in 2014, etc.  If you use the POSIX format, your system can only account for one set of rules.

You should only use time zones that are location based IANA tz identifiers.  Pacific time is `America/Los_Angeles`.  Central time is `America/Chicago`.  etc.  Refer to [the list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) for other examples.